# How to deal with predicates/comparators/functors getting invalidated?

Tags: c++

When using C++ containers (like `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, etc.) how do people address the case where a functor (substitutes for `std::less`, `std::hash`, etc.) that's passed to a container has a member (like a pointer) that might get invalidated between calls to the container?

For illustration, one example might be something with an internal pointer like this:

```
struct Hash  // or Less, etc.
{
    std::vector<size_t>::iterator p;
    size_t operator()(size_t i) { return p[i]; }
};

std::unordered_set<size_t, Hash> container;  // or std::map or whatever
```

As the caller, I know when the member invalidation would occur and I *could* take steps to correct it if I had access to the internal predicate and could overwrite it, but I don't.

There are several ways I could imagine working around it:

- I could store a pointer to the *container* object instead. This adds both an indirection and also still breaks when the container is swapped, so it doesn't really solve the problem.
- I could add an indirection to its payload with a `shared_ptr` (or `intrusive_ptr`, etc.) so I can fix up the payload externally. This would work, but the extra memory access comes at a (slight) performance loss I'm hoping to avoid.
- I could make my predicate do some hackery to "report" its own address upon construction, with the assumption that the container will only maintain one copy of the predicate. This seems the most fragile, but it should be the most performant.

None of them is great, so I'm wondering how people usually deal with this. Is this a known use case? Is there a good solution for it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I might be wrong or extremely paranoid, but I think that having stateful predicates for most of `<algorithm>` functions is broken by definition. In some cases we can't guarantee order or non-concurrent state of calls

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: Interesting, but note that in this case I don't need order or concurrency guarantees, or really any guarantees in the middle of a call for that matter. What the internal iterator/pointer refers to remains entirely unmodified for the duration of any call to the container. It's only in between calls that I need to do something.

Comment: You could store a "reference" to some iterator you can control leverage `std::reference_wrapper` for the type of `p`.

Comment: If that is the case, why not store an index?  That never changes even if the vector grows

Comment: @NathanOliver: What I am *already* doing is storing an index (just look at the example)—hence the need for this entire thing in the first place. Storing yet another index inside the predicate still won't get me the element, I still need a pointer to the underlying container at some point to do the comparison. Hence my first bullet point. And the "reference" trick is my second bullet point.

Comment: `p[i]` is not a valid syntax for iterators afaik

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: It sure is...

Comment: @user541686 it is for pointers, but not sure for iterators. I will check it now

Comment: @user541686 it apparently is for random access iterators. I didn't know that https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili hah curious.. I also only knew that `*(it + i)` was legal for those... but that's kinda consistent with pointers then

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::reference_wrapper`. It's basically a more well-behaved pointer. Doesn't do any allocations:

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

struct Hash {
  std::vector<std::size_t>::iterator p;
  std::size_t operator()(std::size_t i) const noexcept { return p[i]; }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::size_t> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  Hash hash{vec.begin()};

  std::unordered_map<int, int, std::reference_wrapper<Hash>> map(
      0, std::ref(hash));

  map[0] = 0;

  vec.push_back(6);  // likely invalidates

  hash.p = vec.begin();  // validated again

  map[1] = 1;
}
```